# Why do motherboard voltages meet 5v standard when so much seems to work at 5.5?

Tags: capacitor

I am working with supercaps (>1F) for resin embedded purposes. I have an induction charger that says 5v, but it really is outputting 4.85 volt. Caps seem to be commonly in 2.7 and 5.5 volts... although there are some caps at other voltages, 5.5v seems to have way more supercaps than just 5v. Why is this?

I can't really fully charge big 2.7v caps in series (5.4v) but it seems so perfect for a 5.5 volt system. And I have to use a buck converter to get to 5.5 volt... or I have to just resistor drop everything to 2.7/3 and then they don't last anywhere near as long. SO what is the reason for this and how do I deal with this problem?

I could really use some insight. I'm sorry if this has been explained elsewhere... I'm struggling to dig through huge search results with just voltages and basic words for filtering. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Because "5V" has a tolerance ... usually 5%, occasionally 10%. And you'd probably get annoyed if your supercaps blew up with a supply above nominal, but still within tolerance.

Comment: Supercaps come at 2.7V because that's what chemistry says, and 5.5V is just two of them in series. Lithium ion batteries come at 3.2-4.2V so why don't we have 4.2V motherboards? Answer: Why should the motherboard care what voltage lithium ion batteries have?

Answer (score 3):

Well, 5.5V (or 6V or 6.3V) are a common specifications for parts designed to work at 5V with a bit of tolerance. 5.5V for ICs is about as close as you want to call it (10% more than nominal). For example, the [74ACH00](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AHC_AHCT00_Q100.pdf).

Often the 5V is biased a bit higher to account for conductor losses at full load, so you might find a regulated 5V wall wart that outputs 5.1V or even a bit higher with a light load.

You don't want the parts failing if things are just slightly off nominal. For example, the ubiquitous [LM7805](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf) regulator will output between 4.8 and 5.2V.

Comment: Ok that's very helpful. Thanks for the info. I'll avoid over volting my stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> *I could really use some insight.*

A voltage rating of 5.5 volts for a capacitor is the maximum voltage that should be applied i.e. it is a top limit and, any excursion above that top limit is not recommended. Given that a lot of systems run at 5 volts and the 5 volt rail might have an output accuracy between 4.75 volts and 5.25 volts (across load and temperature ranges), then a capacitor suitable for a 5 volt rail must have a voltage rating that is higher than 5.25 volts.

5.5 volts is the chosen rating for a lot of capacitors on this basis.

> *Why do motherboard voltages meet 5v standard when so much seems to
> work at 5.5?*

You should take care to ensure that any system you design cannot supply more voltage to the capacitors than what their maximum rating is. In addition (and especially for electrolytic capacitors), the lifetime of the part can be increased by up to 50% by running at half the rated voltage. I don't know how this might apply to supercaps but I suspect that there is a similar trade-off.

Comment: Ok so this is really helpful. I think part of me is also curious why 5.5 wouldn't be more standard as you can run many 2.7v parts in series on it. Makes sense about the caps though. I figured they had to be charged till they hit max voltage to give the most performance. I'm seeing now it's a trade off. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's tricky sometimes to get to the bottom of things. For instance, why was 5 volts adopted as the standard for logic levels for decades and why it has become 3.3 volts more recently. They came first and 6.3 volt capacitors and 4 volt rated capacitors came 2nd. I think that the 5.5 volt rating for supercaps has a lot to do with 5 volt logic levels. And, let's not forget the 2.5 volt logic standard that has a peak extreme limit of 2.7 volts!

Answer (score 1):

Supercaps come at 2.7V because that's what chemistry says, and 5.5V is just two of them in series.

Lithium ion batteries come at 3.2-4.2V, so don't they have 4.2V motherboards? Obviously they can't be 2.7V and 4.2V at the same time.

Answer: Why should they? Why would computer motherboards care what voltage lithium ion batteries have, or supercapacitors? They don't have lithium ion batteries on them, and they don't have supercapacitors on them. It's simply irrelevant. NASA's ion thrusters run at 3000 volts so why don't we have 3000-volt computer motherboards?

Also, 2.7/5.5V is the maximum rating for a supercap. You probably don't want to go all the way up to the maximum rating.

Answer (score 1):

The use of 5V power supplies goes back to the days when TTL logic chips were used everywhere.  TTL was introduced in the 1960s, long before anybody had ever heard of supercapacitors.

These days, 3.3V logic is also common.  Unfortunately, that doesn't work well with supercapacitors, either.